# jQuery, ready(function() and .click(function() execute differently with the same code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, api

So I have the following code, which displays recipes from an API call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
const APPID = 
const APPKEY = 
const query = "salmon";
const hits = 6;
    
var queryURL = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APPID}&app_key=${APPKEY}&diet=high-protein&calories=100-300&cuisineType=Nordic&to=${hits}`;
console.log(queryURL);

// Grabbing API results
$.ajax({
    url: queryURL,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
  })
    .then (function(response) {
        ...
    }
  });
});
```

My problem occurs when I try to implement a search function.

```
$("#search-btn").click(function(){
    const query = $("#search-text").val();
    const APPID = 
    const APPKEY = 
    const hits = 6;
        
    var queryURL = `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APPID}&app_key=${APPKEY}&diet=high-protein&calories=100-300&cuisineType=Nordic&to=${hits}`;
    console.log(queryURL);

    // Grabbing API results
    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL,
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
      })
        .then (function(response) {
            ...
        }   
      });
});
```

This gives the following error:

> `Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://api.edamam.com/search?q=**myInput**....`

myInput = the text I have entered. I been at this for hours but cant seem to work it out. Any help or suggestions is tremendously welcome.

**Solution**
--PreventDefault();--

Comment: sounds like your button is a submit button. Cancel the action with preventDefault and see if it makes a difference

Comment: May also need some escaping if including spaces or special characters. Try using `encodeURIComponent(query)`